# Moving text inside squares in sequential order starting from bottom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Thinking about a way to move the text contents to specific cells.I am working on the following code, where the blue text can be dragged to any square (this is unrelated to what I'm asking in this post but just thought to mention it). Here's what I'm looking for:

When a user clicks the `Move Text Content!` button, all the text inside the blue color cells on the left of the grid should move inside the grid. The order I want it to follow can be figured out based on the text inside the blue cell.

So, `H1 Text` should move inside `H1` square ; `H2 Text` should move inside `H2` square so on and so forth ... `H6 Text` should move inside `H6` square.

Once it has reached `6th square` starting from row `H`, I would like to start filling next test from `G1`. Hence, `G1 Text` should go inside `G1` square and so on and so forth ...`G6 Text` should go inside `G6` square.

The names inside blue text box is just for proper understanding purpose such that it's easy to know where that text needs to go while figuring out a solution for this. In reality, it's not going to be more than 8-10 characters of text.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for easily using Javascript or jQuery? Do I need to add `id` to each and every `div` of the square where I'm expecting to move my text from blue cell?

```js
/*

Requires jquery + UI

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

*/

$(".words").draggable({
  revert: function (event, ui) {
    var bRevertingPhrase = this.closest("#drop-em");

    if (!bRevertingPhrase.length) {
      var phraseID = $(this).data("id");
      var phraseHomeID = $(this).parent().data("id");

      //If the child and parent ids don't match, we move the child to the correct parent
      if (phraseID !== phraseHomeID) {
        var correctCell = $("#phrase").find("div[data-id='" + phraseID + "']");
        correctCell.prepend(this);
      }
    }
    return !event;
  }
});
$("#drop-em > div").droppable({
  drop: function (ev, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable)
      .detach()
      .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
      .appendTo($(this).find(".content:empty"));
  }
});
$("#phrase > div").droppable({
  drop: function (ev, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).prependTo(this);
  }
});


function moveText(){
  console.log("Inside moveText");
  
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  counter-reset: columnCount 1 alphaCount;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.grid {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  counter-increment: columnCount;
  min-width: 0;
}
.item:nth-of-type(12n + 1) {
  counter-increment: alphaCount;
}
.item:nth-of-type(12n + 1)::before {
  content: counter(alphaCount, upper-alpha);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1.75rem;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.item:nth-of-type(n + 13)::after {
  display: none;
}
.item::after {
  content: counter(columnCount);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: -1.75rem;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.words {
  cursor: move;
  transition: padding 0.5s ease;
}
.content:has(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
  overflow: visible;
}
.ui-droppable-active .content{
  overflow: visible;
}
.ui-droppable-active .content .words{
 
}
.words.ui-draggable-dragging {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
   display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#phrase {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}
#phrase > div {
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #007bff;
  border: 2px solid #007bff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#phrase > div:empty {
  background: #fff;
  border-style: dashed;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- You'd need to set up something different for touch devices though -->
<h1>Drag and drop example </h1>
<button type="button" onclick="moveText()">Move Text Content!</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="phrase">
    <!-- remove whitespace from  inside div html and then we can use :empty in css to change background -->
    <div data-id="1"><span data-id="1" class="words">H1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="2"><span data-id="2" class="words">H2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="3"><span data-id="3" class="words">H3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="4"><span data-id="4" class="words">H4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="5"><span data-id="5" class="words">H5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="6"><span data-id="6" class="words">H6 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="7"><span data-id="7" class="words">G1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="8"><span data-id="8" class="words">G2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="9"><span data-id="9" class="words">G3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="10"><span data-id="10" class="words">G4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="11"><span data-id="11" class="words">G5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="12"><span data-id="12" class="words">G6 Text</span></div>
  </div>

  <div id="drop-em" class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div><!-- must have no spaces inside .content -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
<style>
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  body {
    counter-reset: columnCount 1 alphaCount;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
  }
  
  .grid {
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  .item {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    counter-increment: columnCount;
    min-width: 0;
  }
  
  .item:nth-of-type(12n + 1) {
    counter-increment: alphaCount;
  }
  
  .item:nth-of-type(12n + 1)::before {
    content: counter(alphaCount, upper-alpha);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1.75rem;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .item:nth-of-type(n + 13)::after {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .item::after {
    content: counter(columnCount);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -1.75rem;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #000;
    padding: 1rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  
  .words {
    cursor: move;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  .content:has(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
  .ui-droppable-active .content {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
  .ui-droppable-active .content .words {}
  
  .words.ui-draggable-dragging {
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #phrase {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }
  
  #phrase>div {
    margin: 0 10px 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #007bff;
    border: 2px solid #007bff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
  
  #phrase>div:empty {
    background: #fff;
    border-style: dashed;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    min-height: 30px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- You'd need to set up something different for touch devices though -->
<h1>Drag and drop example </h1>
<button type="button" onclick="moveText()">Move Text Content!</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="phrase">
    <!-- remove whitespace from  inside div html and then we can use :empty in css to change background -->
    <div data-id="1"><span data-id="1" class="words">H1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="2"><span data-id="2" class="words">H2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="3"><span data-id="3" class="words">H3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="4"><span data-id="4" class="words">H4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="5"><span data-id="5" class="words">H5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="6"><span data-id="6" class="words">H6 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="7"><span data-id="7" class="words">G1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="8"><span data-id="8" class="words">G2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="9"><span data-id="9" class="words">G3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="10"><span data-id="10" class="words">G4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="11"><span data-id="11" class="words">G5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="12"><span data-id="12" class="words">G6 Text</span></div>
  </div>

  <div id="drop-em" class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
      <!-- must have no spaces inside .content -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(".words").draggable({
    revert: function(event, ui) {
      var bRevertingPhrase = this.closest("#drop-em");

      if (!bRevertingPhrase.length) {
        var phraseID = $(this).data("id");
        var phraseHomeID = $(this).parent().data("id");

        //If the child and parent ids don't match, we move the child to the correct parent
        if (phraseID !== phraseHomeID) {
          var correctCell = $("#phrase").find("div[data-id='" + phraseID + "']");
          correctCell.prepend(this);
        }
      }
      return !event;
    }
  });
  $("#drop-em > div").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable)
        .detach()
        .css({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        })
        .appendTo($(this).find(".content:empty"));
    }
  });
  $("#phrase > div").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).prependTo(this);
    }
  });

  function moveText() {
    console.log("Inside moveText");
    $('.words').each((index, item) => {
      const text = item.innerText
      if (text) {
        const row = text[0].charCodeAt() - 65;
        const column = text[1] - 1;
        $(this).remove();
        const target = $(".content")[12 * row + column]
        target.append(item)
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes. One question I would like to ask. So your solution I believe will work for my other scenario as well - for eg. if I had `F1..F6`, `D1..D6`, `C1-C6`, `B1..B6` and `A1..A6`. Once it fills up to the top, until A6, I would like to start it again from the bottom for the remaining half of the grid. So for example,  `H7...H12` will go at the bottom, then `G7 to G12` and so on and so forth until `A7 to A12`, which will basically fill up all the cells of the grid. Do I need to modify the `moveText()` function to accomplish this?

Comment: another thing I noticed is that your code breaks if I use some different text. For example, when I replaced `H1 Text` with `ABCD` as shown in this JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/q26nsajo/1/), it starts complaining `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append'` . If I put the text back to `H1 Text`, it will start working again.  Any idea what's wrong after changing the text?

Comment: First question, I think it easy to modify  If the grid was written by yourself. second question, I think you may not  understand what I did on function moveText, ,I use  two variables( row and column) to confirm the position of the target element  in the grid, like: A3 -> (0,2), C1 -> (2,0),If the text change to ABCD ,I dont known where I should place it ,

Comment: I see. In that case, I don't think your solution is going to work since that text can be any string of 8 characters.  Another approach I am thinking of is to assign sequential ids to the ` <div class="content"></div>` and then loop over all the text elements in the blue color box and put it inside each cell. If you could think of any other approach that is going to satisfy my requirement, feel free to discuss it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you may move the positon information to somewhere like this: <span data-id="1" class="words" data-position="H1">ABCD</span>

Comment: Hmm, you mean by having the position information like `data-position="H1"`, your code could still be usable?

Comment: Of course the code needs  modify,I'm just explaining the principle, hope it was helpful